# Rendered audio plays in slow-mo

Tags: web-audio-api, audio-processing, audiocontext

When decoding the audio data of an mp3 file I fetched, rendering it with my `OfflineContext`, and exporting it back to a .wav file, the sound is in slo-mo with a different pitch. Is it because the sample rates of my mp3 file and `OfflineContext` are different? If it is, how can I export the mp3 file in a different sample rate while not changing the pitch?

**Edit:**

I run `decodeAudioData` with the `OfflineAudioContext` that I use for the rendering: `offlineContext.decodeAudioData(this.arrayBuffer)`. The sample rate of `offlineContext` is 48000, while the sample rate of my `audioContext` (used for normal playback, which works well) is 41000.

Comment: Please provide an example.  Did you run `decodeAudioData` using the `OfflineAudioContext` that you used for rendering?

Comment: Hi, please see my edit.

Comment: An example of the whole thing would be nice.  How you do play back the wav file?

Comment: While editing my post to add a more complete example, I realized that I was setting the wrong sample rate in the WAV file header. Thanks for the help. I noticed though, that the resulting WAV file (which contains the audio converted from 44100 to 48000) is a little bit distorted, just like if it was clipping. Any idea on what could be causing that?

Comment: `decodeAudioData` will resample the audio  to the sample rate of the context.  This can cause some distortion.  But without the actual source code and test files, I can't really say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the WAV file, the same sample rate than the offline context should be set in the WAV file header. For example, a WAV file with a sample rate of 44100 in the header that contains data chunks with a sample rate of 48000 will cause the playback to be in "slow motion" in iTunes.